# Jasmine not catching errors within Try/Catch

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

I've been writing some angularjs tests using the Jasmine Framework. I'm confused by the documentation on the Jasmine site

> The 'toThrow' matcher is for testing if a function throws an exception

Jasmine will pass the following test if I do not wrap the body of submission.save in a try/catch

```
it("should not save to server if user is invalid", function () {
    userServiceMock.user.id = false;
    expect(function () {
      submissionService.save(submission);
    }).toThrow();
   userServiceMock.user.id = 15;
});
```

I don't think it is good practice to throw errors without a catch clause. So I must be writing this type of test wrong. Hoping someone can clarify this.

I'm using gruntjs and grunt-karma to run my tests.

Answer (score 0):

You will test that your function will throw an error. To do so you can't set the block that will throw an error into a try catch/block cause then no error is thrown in this function even if it was thrown in a function your function calls.

What [jasmine does](https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine/blob/master/src/core/matchers/toThrowError.js#L17) is to catch the error in the `toThrow` matcher and the test will only pass when the `catch` block in the matcher was called:

```
    try {
      actual();
    } catch (e) {
      threw = true;
      thrown = e;
    }
```

Comment: So then my actual code should not be wrapped in a try/catch construct?

Comment: Yes, the error must be catch from the jasmine matcher, otherwise the test fails.

Comment: So i will end up commenting my try/catch block for testing, and removing comment for actucl execution??